# WHMCS - How to get payment link to paypal

Tags: api, paypal, payment-gateway, whmcs

I implementing whole billing system with WHMCS in the background, and calling it via API. Now I'm stuck when client completes billing form and selects paypal as payment gateway i need to immediately take him to paypal page to complete purchase, but i didn't found any API calls to get paypal form. Any direction or documentation will be appreciate.

Comment: You can refer to https://www.webhostinghero.com/whmcs-paypal-setup/ about how to configure PayPal in WHMCS.

Comment: @ZhaoSamanta thanks for feedback but this I already did, my question is about connecting paypal page via whmcs api, i send ticket to whmcs about this question i got answer that it can't be done at moment and to request it as new feature

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own API call by adding a file to the API folder within your WHMCS installation, and adding the api call name to the "permissions" field, in the existing entry of the "tblapi_roles" table; in the database.

In your custom api code, you can do whatever you want.

I'm not sure about the specifics of a paypal payment, with the database... i guess it would be determined by which payment module (version) you were specifically using for PayPal payments. (i'll let you do the research on the rest ;-) )